# In app purchases after they've expired don't have a record in the app's license info's AddOnLicenses property

Tags: windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm having a problem with my durable in-app-purchases. For testing purposes, I have set the premium trial IAP for my app to expire after a day. I copied the following code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/monetize/get-license-info-for-apps-and-add-ons to obtain the app's license info:

```
    private StoreContext context = null;
    private async Task<bool> getLicenseInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
            }

            StoreAppLicense appLicense = await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();

            // license wasn't retrieved, for example because user is offline, so..
            // need to fallback on non-premium version
            if (appLicense == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // iterate through the add on licenses for add-ons for this app.
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StoreLicense> item in appLicense.AddOnLicenses)
            {
                StoreLicense addOnLicense = item.Value;
                if (addOnLicense.InAppOfferToken.Equals("test1_premium"))
                    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["PremiumPurchased"] = addOnLicense.IsActive;
                else if (addOnLicense.InAppOfferToken.Equals("test1_premiumTrial"))
                    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["PremiumTrialActive"] = addOnLicense.IsActive;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

During the 24 hours after the premium trial IAP was purchased, the premium trial IAP is returned in appLicense.AddOnLicenses, and is correctly set to active with the correct expiration time. However, after approximately a day (I'm not 100%), appLicense.AddOnLicenses no longer contains a record for the IAP (and so the loop isn't entered resulting in the value of the RoamingSetting to indicate the active status of the IAP not being updated to reflect that it may have expired i.e. false).

The fact IAPs have an isActive property to me suggests that IAPs even after they've expired should still retain a record in appLicense.AddOnLicenses, albeit with isActive set to false. What I'm seeing however may suggest otherwise. Can someone please provide any clarification on this? If it's confirmed that an expired IAP does have its record removed, then it will be straightforward - just set the IAP's RoamingSetting to false if no record was found. However, I've a feeling something else is going on here which may require a different solution.

Comment: I can now confirm that the IAP's AddOnLicense gets removed exactly 1 minute after its expiration date. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: I am testing this and It will take 1-2 days for the app to expire, if I have any update info, I will post here.

Comment: Microsoft changed its documentation so it fits with reality : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-license-info-for-apps-and-add-ons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the expired IAP will have its record removed in my app, in this way we need to do some records as you said using the RoamingSetting to check if the IAP is expired or not.

Besides, I will consult the related team to see if it is a expected behavior.

Another workaround is to implement the IAP using the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.aspx) namespace and we can use the following method to check the IAP's expiration date:

```
LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
if(licenseInformation.ProductLicenses[productId].IsActive)
  {
     var productLicense1 = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses[productId];
     var longdateTemplate = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("longdate");
     MyExpireDataTextBlock.Text = "ExpirationDate" + longdateTemplate.Format(productLicense1.ExpirationDate) + ". remain days: " + (productLicense1.ExpirationDate - DateTime.Now).Days;

   }
 else
   {

   }
```